# cUrl Converting into Javascript possible?

Tags: php, javascript, curl

is there a way to convert this into javascript?

```
  <?php
      $url = 'http://www.yourdomain.com/';
      $ch = curl_init();

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
      $output = curl_exec($ch); 
      curl_close($ch);

      echo $output;
    ?>
```

Comment: Why do you need to move it to js? What platform is this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure JavaScript? No.

JavaScript with a standard browser environment? Maybe. There is the [XHR object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) (which includes the `status` property, which will tell you if it was successful or not), but there is also the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You can use `XMLHttpRequest` to download webpages, but there are [cross-domain issues](http://www.google.com/search?q=cross-domain+javascript) to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't but you can:**

Actually you can save the php code to, let's say, mycurl.php, in your server, then use AJAX (`XMLHttpRequest`) to pass the url to mycurl.php and get back the response to your javascript function.